# Struts2 - validation failure using xml file causes action class paramters to disappear from resulting jsp

Tags: struts2, struts

I have a class A :

```
class A extends ActionSupport{

  int someId;
  // getters/setters

  public String execute(){
    setSomeId(2);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String save(){
   // something
  }

}
```

In `struts.xml`, I have configured an action "`ViewId`" that takes us to the default method `execute`, where `someId` is set. Then, we are taken to a jsp page `show.jsp` where I can access the `someId` value. In show.jsp, I have to enter an email id and then submit the page. The action that's now called in "`Save`" that takes us to the save method of the action class. But, I have given some checks in the corresponding validation.xml file `A-Save-validation.xml`, which will check the email entered for a format. The problem is that if the xml validation fails, we are taken back to show.jsp, but the viewId parameter is now not available. Why is this so ?

The input page should appear similar to the user as before. Only the fields that are now validated should have an error page associated with them. Any workaround for this ?

Comment: that is because you actual method never get called as validation is failing, simple approach is to use prepare method since it will get called before workflow interceptor will send back in case of validation error

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Please mention this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Umesh said, validation happens on the corresponding interecptor, **before** the action's method is called.

When validation fails, the action's method is never called and you will be taken to the INPUT result.

In order to achieve what you want you have some options:

1. Implement the preparable interface in your action
2. Peform the validation inside your method.
3. Use s:action in your jsp before the items you want populated to call an action that populates the relevant section

1 is probably the easiest. I like option 3 as well.